# Power BI - Programming Lanaguage (does it have one)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Ive just had a Power BI report sent to me where it has tables (Direct Query) connected to our SQL server.

On our SQL server, we have Multiple Databases (identical schemas) for each physical region (country).  The creator of the report asked can we have a button or set of buttons with each region where it swaps the database to that selected region.

My response was initially "yeah no problem" thinking we could just use some VBA to change the SQLConnection string to use a different database.

I've since learned that there is no VBA in Power BI.  So my question is - is there a different language we use?  Is this even possible to do.

This is a Desktop file.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI doesn't have a programming language like Excel. You'll need to use M/PowerQuery to change the data connection, and then use the report layer to change the data connection on the fly.

The MS documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-dynamic-m-query-parameters) outlines the process of dynamic query parameters. I would recommended to consolidate your separate databases into one reporting database, then you can then use the standard filtering, and row level security to control access to data, as dynamically changing data sources in desktop maybe a security risk, if you are using the same authentication credentials to access data.

Comment: Thanks for the info...yes that will be the long term goal.  Power BI reports are at concept stage right now.